# URL regex from plain text?

Tags: php, regex

How to modify this regex compatible with `https://sub.domain.com`?

`/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/`
`/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/sub\.domain\.com[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/`

Comment: Two ways: 1) building a silly simple pattern and then using `parse_url` to check the matches (something like `\b(?:ht|f)tps?://\S+`). 2) to study more regex and to build your own pattern for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This pattern works, but now it grabs all links with `https etc`, all i need to do is add specific domain name.

Comment: Now use `parse_url` to filter the results.

Answer (score -1):

#### UPDATE:

link & pattern are updated.

You can test it here: http://regexr.com/3fibn

```
/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/sub\.domain\.com(\/)?/
```